# How to simply generate the CREATE SQL script for a table and data?

Tags: sql-server

So i'm used to PHPMySQL where if I want to transfer a table from one database to another, I:

- go to the table
- click "export"
- CTRL-C
- go to the other database, insert SQL, CTRL-V

In MS SQL Server 2008 Express, I try:

- right-click, script table as, CREATE TO

  - but this only gives me the CREATE TABLE sql, not the INSERT INTO sql
- right-click, script table as, INSERT TO

  - this gives me INSERT TO sql but assumes that I am going to fill in the data (!)
- so I fire up the SQL Server 2008 Express Import/Export Data Wizard, but it doesn't seem to give me the simple CREATE/INSERT INTO script that I want either. :-(

So how can I get a simple SQL dump of a table in MS SQL Server 2008 Express, the kind that PHPMySQL gives me:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.9.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 23, 2008 at 03:34 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.67
-- PHP Version: 5.2.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `members`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstName` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--

INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'Jim', 'Taylor', 34),
(2, 'John', 'McGregor', 23),
(3, 'Alice', 'Anderson', 33);
```

Answer (score 82):

From the SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on your database and select:

Tasks -> Generate Scripts - Next -> Select objects that you need from list -> click on the advanced 
Then simply proceed through the wizard. Make sure to set 'Script Data' to TRUE when prompted to choose the script options.

SQL Server 2008

[image]

SQL Server 2008 R2

[image]

Further reading:

Robert Burke: SQL Server 2005 - Scripting your Database

Taken from stack overflow:
[How to get script of SQL Server data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. No extensions or paid add ons needed. Did the job appropriately.

Comment: for newer sql server management studio version, you should press advanced button and set `Types of data to script` option to 'schema and data'

Answer (score 3):

Look here: [Simon Holywell: SQL Server 2005 Dump to SQL statements](http://www.simonholywell.com/article/sql-server-2005-dump-to-sql-statements.html).

What Simon says (no pun intended) is this: There is nothing built-in, but there is a "scripting way" to do it. He made a PHP script you can use.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the database publishing wizard to do that

http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard

Comment: This was the cleanest (and most configurable) way to export a table to an SQL script. This functionality should have been in SSMSE.