# SQL: How do I port sql server database via t-sql scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have to port sql server (2008) database with t-sql scripts. I can generate "create" script per each database object (stored procedure, table) from Sql Server Management Studio (though it looks to take much time)

How do I port data for tables? I'd like to have scripts like that:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)
...
```

Can I generate such scripts from Sql Server Management Studio or is there some free 3'rd party utility for that? (I guess there should be).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get script of SQL Server data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data)

Answer (score 2):

The (free) [SMSS Tool pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=8) addin can generate insert scripts for a DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing bulk inserts of data, I'd suggest using bulk insert.  You can do the insert from T-SQL, but I prefer to use the bcp command line utility as I can do both the export and import with minimal change to the run line.  Oh... and it runs a lot faster than a bunch of insert statements.  Have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) and see if it fits your purposes.