# MS SQL Server with management studio - how to script a table with its data (as insert statements)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get script of SQL Server data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data)

I want to move some rows from 1 table (on one server) to another (on another server).

The table schema is the same, what I need to do is generate some insert statements. Is there a way to do this using some built in / best practice way?

Import / Export seems completely extreme and excessive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data

Comment: @Niklas: Really great duplicate also including images...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right-click on the database name and choose *Tasks* -> *Generate Scripts*. On the *Scripting Options* screen set *Script Data* to true.

Comment: This is great! I usually do just a select and copy data into Notepad++ and do few replacements using regular expressions. Fast as well, but not as fast as this one is. Great to know. +1

Comment: **FYI**: I don't know which SQL Server/SSMS version you're using, but you have to set *Advanced* properties and the one that's relevant here is **Type of data to script** where you either select **Data only** or **Schema and data**. That's of course related to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the publish wizard

> Maybe it’s well-known, but new to me, you can just run “C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4\SqlPubWiz.exe”. This nifty little tool
>   can generate INSERT script very easily.

Reference [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/06/24/sql-server-2008-r2-generating-insert-statements-for-a-table.aspx)