# Generating Schema and Data for SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I have Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services for 2008.

I only see script option for the database and not for Schema and Data.

Is this feature available in SQL Server Express Edition?

I came across a resource which mentioned.

From within SQL Management Studio Express I can use
Generate and Publish Script and click on advanced and get Advanced Scriptiong options and specify Schema and metadata.

I don't see this option in my Express Edition is this option available only in SQL Server 2012?

Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works.

SQL Server 2008 -

Tasks -> Generate Scripts -

Select the database to be scripted and then. 
Table/View options - Script Data = True.

This solved my problem.

Refer to - [How to get script of SQL Server data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data)