# Creating dump of specific table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to copy data from specific tables to another database.
Both databases are not connected(destination database doesnt allow remote access) otherwise i would have used task/export data from one source to another destination.
 i have already created schema in the destination database by using generate script option from source.
now i want data from select few tables from source to go into the matching tables in destination. the task/export option allows me to create flat file but i have to do that for each table, is there any way i could select few table in one go and create a dump and import that into the destination tables?

NOE: i have already generated the scripts and created the schema in the destination db, with all objects, tables, stored procedures, users and triggers. but i want to load SELECTIVE tables with the data now, i would use the export utility to map each and every table, but the two databases arent connected so i need to created a database back up(ok i wont call it dump) either in csv, or flat file to load data in selective tables

Comment: Stop thinking about "dumps" (this is not a SQL Server concept at all) and either (a) use the import/export wizard or (b) generate a script for the table but this time choose to script data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned, script table 'with' data is the way to go. It will generate a .sql file which you can execute on the destination server.Look at this, already answered question: [How to get script of SQL Server data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data)
Thanks.

Comment: guys sorry if i wasnt clear, i have already generated the scripts and created the schema in the destination db, with all objects, tables, stored procedures, users and triggers. but i want to load those tables with the data, i would use the export utility to map each and every table, but the two databases arent connected so i need to created a dabase back up with either in csv, or flat file to load data in selective tables

Comment: ok script data only is the way to go, i have just noticed the option