# Migrate data from one db to another

Tags: sql-server

I have two different databases. I have tried using an `UPDATE` query, but it comes back with an `unrecognised error` .

How can I reference the DB in the SQL query.

The location is like this for both:

> SERVER01\ABC.DB1

And

> SERVER01.DB2

EDIT 1:

I have tried

```
insert into [DB1].[dbo].[table1]
select col1 from [ABC.DB2].[dbo].[table2]
```

But, I get this error,

```
Invalid object name 'ABC.DB2.dbo.table2'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the database name in the query:

```
insert into [DbName1].[dbo].[Table1]
select * from [ABC.DB2].[dbo].[Table1]
```

Comment: why would I be inserting and selecting from `DbName1`?

Comment: @AndroidAL yes, sorry, It should be `DbName2` - updated

Comment: it returns this error `Invalid object name 'server01\ABC.DB2.dbo.table1'.` I can update question to show what I have tried?

Comment: @AndroidAL you don't need to include server name in the request - both databases are on the same server. Also try enclosing database name, schema name and table in square brackets `[]`. Added another update to my answer. And you should be able to edit your question.

Comment: @AndroidAL in this case are you sure that all the names (including schema name) are correct?

Comment: yes , I have checked them 3 times, is there another way that this could be done?

Comment: Well, you can Generate scripts with data from one DB and execute them on on the other table, but this is impractical if you have a large dataset.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a script or were I might find one?

Comment: @AndroidAL Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2321082/809357 or here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/18/sql-server-generate-script-for-schema-and-data-sql-in-sixty-seconds-021-video/