# How to convert my database into exe or script file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I Have a Database in **SQLServer**. Now i Need to convert my database as a exe or script . is it possible ?

My exact need is i want to give my database to my tester.with in a single click he need to store my database.so i choose to convert my database as a exe or script. if any other good methods there plz suggest me.

Comment: The answer for your question is a plain and simple NO, you can't. What you can do is create an executable, or a script that will RESTORE a exported database into the your test machine. You will need to export it first and add it on your executable and/or your script.

Comment: Why don't you just give your tester access to the database being tested?

Comment: my tester expects me," he need only one file that should create database and tables"

Comment: but in Mysql i took script file using SqlYog.But in sql-server i dono

Comment: Just create a new user (TESTER) with read only access ! And share connection details with tester.

Comment: Unless your database is going to be distributed in this manner and you're testing the deployment/distribution process, your tester does not need you to do this. Give him the appropriate access to a test instance of your database and let him test against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate Database into script file

right click on your database go to task and then Generate script then follow Instructions

finally you'll get your database in script file

Comment: Minus 1.  I tried this and did not see any create table, create function, etc commands.

Comment: I don't know y down vote check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/get-script-of-sql-server-data

Comment: It's fully documented how to generate scripts from SSMS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create an sfx archive with:

- MS SQL Server Express installer,
- full database backup and
- autorun command file.

Through autorun:

1. verify there is MS SQL Server available (verify login too)
2. if not - install one;
3. restore database from the backup.

Answer (score -2):

step by step 
1 open ssms 
2 right click on database 
3 tasks
4.generate scripts
5.then next >>> next >>> next >>> next 
NOTE: you can generate only part of the database at step 5 
good luck